# How to select specific option using ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am starting with an array of sources

```
$scope.sources = [
        {
            "type": "register",
            "name": "Register 1",
            "balance": 100
        },
        {
            "type": "register",
            "name": "Register 2",
            "balance": 100
        },
        {
            "type": "register",
            "name": "Register 3",
            "balance": 200
        },
        {
            "type": "office",
            "name": "Change Drawer",
            "balance": 200
        },
        {
            "type": "office",
            "name": "Safe",
            "balance": 500
        }
];
```

I'm successfully loading the options

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Transfer <strong>{{amount(count, start, selectedItem.balance) | currency}}</strong> To:</label>
    <select id="transferTo" class="form-control" ng-model="form.to" ng-options="item.name for item in sources | filter:{type:'office'}">
        <option value="">-- Select a Source --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I've tried using a `$timeout` function to select it after it works, but it doesn't pass back the correct value to my function

```
$timeout(function () {
    $('#transferTo').val('1');
}, 200);
```

How would I set the "Safe" as the default option selected when the form loads?

Comment: What value do you want `form.to` to be set to?  In order to uniquely identify each option.

Comment: You need to set the `form.to` scope property to the selected value.

Comment: I really need the entire object back. I did have `item.balance as item.name for item in sources | filter:{type:'office'}`, which passed the balance back, but I need the entire object to update something up scope

Comment: Then, you need to set `form.to` to the "Safe" array object.  Because it will use the object reference to compare for selected value.  You can also look at the `track by` clause for `ng-options`.

Comment: @DavinTryon Excellent point about using `track by` as it will allow you to essentially specify a field for which to do the matching on for the selected item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set a value on your scope that you're setting ng-model equal to:

```
$scope.form.to = $scope.sources[4];
```

If your list (sources) is dynamic you can filter the array like this, which will return an array (but leave your array untouched).

```
filterFilter($scope.sources, {name: 'Safe'})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9ZV6/)